# dateFromString() returning wrong date swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift3

i am passing "01/12/2017" in the fromDate.text(textfield), but receiving unexpected output.

```
      let formatter = DateFormatter.init()
      formatter.dateFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
      startDate = formatter.date(from: fromDate.text!)
      print("startDate = \(startDate)")
```

output is : 31/12/2016

Comment: The date is printed in UTC (zero) time zone. That's a problem with printing, not a problem with your date.

Comment: Its suppose to be MM not mm

Comment: Do you make an app that will calculate time before the New Year? Also, why Swift 3.0? Everyone use Swift 4.0 now.

Comment: @kelin `Everyone use Swift 4.0` -  I don't think so. Any stats ?

Comment: @AdityaSrivastava, here it is: [Swift version stats.](https://i.imgur.com/1apEkfR.png)

Comment: so that's not everyone ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The format of date should be `dd/MM/yyyy` not `dd/mm/yyyy`. The `mm` indicates the minutes and `MM` indicates the month.

And also add the below line in your code

```
formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT+0:00")
```

This line of code set time zone. If you not, then you get `30/11/2017` in output.

The reason behind this is when string date not contain time then formatter assume that it is midnight and you also not given the timezone so it will take current timezone.

Comment: `TimeZone(secondsFromGTM: 0)` is far better than using a string.

Answer (score 3):

It has to be `dd/MM/yyyy` dateformat. `MM` in capital.

Answer (score 0):

```
 func convertToString(of dateTo: Date) -> String {

        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy" //Your New Date format as per requirement change it own

        let newDate: String = dateFormatter.string(from: dateTo) //pass Date here

        print(newDate) //New formatted Date string

        return newDate
    }
```